# Materialize how to change second select option depended from the first?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I use materialize, and the problem is:
I have 2 select-div with options, and when I choose Ukraine in the first select? The second select would show me only Lviv, Odessa, Kiev, kharkiv. If I choose Poland in the first select, the second select would show me only Warsaw and Krakow.

I've already asked the same question, and received few answers which was useful, but when I linked materialize CSS, code doesn't work.

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="country-list" onchange="changeCountry(this)">
        <option value="none" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Ukraine </option>
        <option value="2">Poland</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="city-list">
        <option value="none" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Lviv</option>
        <option value="1">Kiev</option>
        <option value="1">Kharkiv</option>
        <option value="1">Odessa</option>
        <option value="2">Krakow</option>
        <option value="2">Warsaw</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And here JavaScript

```js
var countryObject = {
    Ukraine: ["Lviv", "Kiev", "Kharkiv", "Odessa"],
    Poland: ["Krakow", "Warsaw"],
};

function changeCountry() {
    document.getElementById("city-list").options.length = 0;

    var cityListArray =
        countryObject[document.getElementById("country-list").value];
    console.log(document.getElementById("city-list").options);

    for (var item = 0; item < cityListArray.length; item++) {
        document.getElementById("city-list").options[
            document.getElementById("city-list").options.length
        ] = new Option(cityListArray[item], cityListArray[item]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to continuously find the elements on the page. Find them once, and use the resulting element later when needed.

```js
const countryObject = {
 Ukraine: ["Lviv", "Kiev", "Kharkiv", "Odessa"],
 Poland: ["Krakow", "Warsaw"],
};

const countryListEl = document.getElementById("country-list");
const cityListEl = document.getElementById("city-list");
const defaultOption = new Option("Choose your option");
defaultOption.disabled = true;
defaultOption.selected = true;

function changeCountry() {
 cityListEl.options.length = 0;
 cityListEl.options[0] = defaultOption;

 const cityListArray = countryObject[countryListEl.value];

 for (let i = 0; i < cityListArray.length; i++) {
  cityListEl.options[i + 1] = new Option(
   cityListArray[i],
   cityListArray[i]
  );
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="country-list" onchange="changeCountry(this)">
        <option value="none" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine </option>
        <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="city-list">
        <option value="none" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: When i choose Ukraine, second select box have nothing,but when i close it label change to Lviv

Comment: Hmmm.. it is working for me like a charm right now. Kinda at a loss.. What browser are you using?

Comment: It's work for me to when I create,a new project,but in this one I use materialize and everything complicated

Comment: Can you update your question with regards to materialize being the issue? With the contextual information provided in your initial question, this solves the problem. The question needs to have all relevant information in order to provide adequate assistance.